# Set to 1 if checkbox is checked?

Tags: angular

I have mutiple checkboxes. What i want is when user check some of them to call method and do something in that method. Any suggestion how can i do that?

I tried this:

```
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="checked == 1 ? true : checked == 0 ? false : null" (ngModelChange)="checked = $event ? 1 : 0">

   ngOnChanges(){
        console.log(this.checked);
    }
```

But onChanges never call when i check or uncheck.

Also i tried this:

```
 <input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="checked == 1 ? true : checked == 0 ? false : null" (ngModelChange)="setValue(checked)">
```

But also not working.

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnChanges()` is only called (on the child component) when change detection detects a change on the parent component and updates an `@Input()` of the child component the changed value is bound to.

Your example is in no way related to `ngOnChanges()`

What you can do is

```
(ngModelChange)="checked = $event ? 1 : 0; callSomeMethod()"
```

or

```
(ngModelChange)="callSomeMethod($event)"
```

```
callSomeMethod(e) {
  this.checked = $event ? 1 : 0
}
```

Comment: which of the 2 examples?

Comment: I have this:
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked" (ngModelChange)="setValue($event,2)"> but problem is then that i can not user checked variable on other inputs. Do i need then multiple variables or i can use only one somehow?

Comment: In .ts i have this:

  if(e && checked===1){
            console.log("checked 1");
        }
        if(e && checked===2){
            console.log("checked 2");
        }

but when i check first second is checked also

Comment: And what code have you used in the `<input ...>` binding?

Comment: Im using this for every input:
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked" (ngModelChange)="setValue($event,2)">

Comment: What's the `, 2` for? and how does the signature of `setValue(...)` look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149712/discussion-between-none-and-gunter-zochbauer).